# What resolution should large formatted photography be for print?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, print-design, images, resolution, photography

I have been given a request to re-size and up the resolution on a handful of images to be printed 40 in. x 30 in. to be hung on the walls in a new facility conference room where clients will see them. A lot of the images I've been given are pretty lo-res (10 in x 8 in, 96 dpi), so obviously when I try to re-size them to 40 in x 30 in, the quality decreases significantly.

So my question really is, do you think I need to get a photographer to go out and shoot new images (these are the only images they have on file), or do you think just upping the resolution in Photoshop on the images I've been given will do the trick?

If we need to re-shoot, what file size/format should as ask to receive from the photographer? And if I can just re-size what resolution do you think it should be in order fpr the images to look clear for viewing?

Answer (score 1):

If there is a luxury of possibility to re-shoot, I would ask your photographer to re-shoot at the highest possible megapixel that your photographer's camera allow. In this case I would suggest min of 18megapixel setting. and printing your image at atleast 150dpi. This should look still good from close distance.

Other option is to use 3rd party plugins for photoshop to upsize without loosing quality. Softwares like: PerfectResize [link](http://www.ononesoftware.com/products/resize8/)

Also please refer to this [link](http://digitalphotographylive.com/megapixels-vs-print-size/) how megapixels vs print size work! Helpful

Answer (score 1):

You can't actually increase the resolution of an image once you have it, unless the photographer has a higher quality file that you can go back to. I would suggest getting RAW files if you reshoot because they are lossless/ not compressed by the camera.